# Representation of angular momentum as bivector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, geometric-algebras

I read about derivation of angular velocity and angular momentum here - https://peeterjoot.com/archives/geometric-algebra/angular_acc.pdf

Peeter Joot wrote: "writing the angular momentum as ..." (see on the image below)

[image]

I have a question about this formulation. How does author know that $r \land p$ is angular momentum? It's not obvious for me.

Thanks.

Comment: That's covered in any book on mechanics. See [this](https://openstax.org/books/college-physics/pages/10-introduction-to-rotational-motion-and-angular-momentum)

Comment: It is the *definition* of angular momentum.

Comment: @TedShifrin I asked about it because author derived angular momentum as bivector but not pseudovector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of geometric algebra it's usually considered a definition. But, for any vectors $v, w$ and $I$ the right-handed pseudoscalar
$$
  v\wedge w = (v\times w)I
$$
where $\times$ is the cross product. This can be confirmed in components, or if you know that $v\times w$ is the Hodge star of $v\wedge w$ you can confirm that
$$
  \star X = \widetilde XI
$$
for any multivector $X$ and where $\widetilde X$ is the reversal.